# Malformed Response - Invoking one ESB REST service from another

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I am relatively new to WSO2 ESB, 
Trying to invoke a REST Web service with GET parameter which is hosted on WSO2 ESB through another REST API.

This is a simple **Web service(SampleREST)** which replies with welcome messsage in XML format, 
When i am invoking this service directly; i can see the correct **response** on browser, shown below

```
<Message xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">WelcomeRanjan</Message>
```

Now i created **another REST web service(InvokeSampleRest) which in turn invokes SampleREST web service** with the parametrized GET, 
the Invoke WebService Client **returns me the XML response wrapped inside the mediator xml tag and other malformed tags**, shown below

```
<mediate><<Message xmlns>"http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">WelcomeRanjan&lt;/Message></<Message xmlns></mediate>
```

**Here is my Code for the SampleREST API**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SampleREST" context="/SampleRest" hostname="10.203.245.47">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{str1}">
        <inSequence>
            <header name="To" action="remove"/>
            <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
            <payloadFactory>
                <format>
                    <Message>$1</Message>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.str1')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log level="full" separator=",">
                <property name="sequence" value="*** Got Request ***"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**The code for the InvokeSampleREST code is as shown below( i am calling SampleREST service from here )**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="InvokeSampleREST" context="/InvokeSampleREST" hostname="10.203.245.47">
       <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{str1}">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full" separator=","/>
            <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat('/Welcome',get-property('uri.var.str1'))" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="sequence" value="****Message Sent *** "/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://10.203.245.47:8280/SampleRest/"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full" separator=",">
                <property name="out" value="** Ouput of Rest call ***"/>
            </log>
            <property name="ContentType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Ranjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using two APIs? You can design your flow, in a single API. I mean you can merge them together.
BTW, you need to set the contentType property in your backend API(ie:At SampleREST API)
Because, when you send back the response to "InvokeSampleREST" API, System doesnt know the content-type of the incoming response and try to handle it as text message.

Eg:

```
 <api name="SampleREST" context="/SampleRest" hostname="localhost">
      <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{str1}">
         <inSequence>
            <header name="To" action="remove"/>
            <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
            <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory>
               <format>
                  <Message>$1</Message>
               </format>
               <args>
                  <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.str1')"/>
               </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log level="full" separator=",">
               <property name="sequence" value="*** Got Request ***"/>
            </log>
            <property name="Content-Type"
                      value="application/xml"
                      scope="transport"
                      type="STRING"/>
            <send/>
         </inSequence>
         <faultSequence/>
      </resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following change at the InvokeSampleREST API.

At the outSequence, set the messageType as follows before the <send> mediator.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: Hi Isuru, I tried the above mentioned property in the code but, still the Response is same. Can you please check if it works for you.